# ListView styling

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am currently fighting against a Listview, I'm trying to have two images (with headlines on etc.) beside each other, but I can't figure it out.

My code looks like this:

```
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="LWArticleList">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table id="TableArticleList" class="repclass">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="thumb main">
                            <p class="thumb-comment">
                                <asp:HyperLink ID="CommentHyperLink" runat="server" CssClass="comment-count">10</asp:HyperLink></p>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="ArticleLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Article.aspx?id={0}", Eval("ID")) %>'>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Width="250px" Height="170px" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# string.Format("{0}/{1}", ImageService.ImageLocation, Eval("Image")) %>' />
                            </asp:HyperLink>
                            <div class="thumb-title">
                                <h2><asp:HyperLink ID="LinkTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Headline") %>' /></h2>
                                <p><asp:Literal ID="LitSummary" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Summary") %>' /></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

I wish my content to be shown like this:

```
Article 1 | Article 2
Article 3 | Article 4
```

But at the moment mine looks like this:

```
Article 1
Article 2
Article 3
Article 4
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because you only have one table cell `<td>` so this will only ever be a 1 column listview.

For example, to display a two-column table, you would render three table cells (`<td>`) in each table row (`<tr>`), like so:

```
<table ...>
   <tr>
      <td>Article 1</td>
      <td>Article 2</td>       
   </tr>

   ...

   <tr>
      <td>Article N - 1</td>
      <td>Article N</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That right there fixed it all! I removed the display:inline-block for my table css to see if your solution did the job, and it did. Thank Paul!

Comment: No worries, glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying your data in a table for each item in your data source.  You should rethink that approach.

Tables' display property is block by default, so this is why your items display as they do.

Comment: I didn't know Tables' display property was block by default, it does help to know that because setting the table to inline-block helps. But do you have any better suggestion?